# Notification in react native

Tags: react-native

I am  New to React Native and i want to implement Notification In React Native so for that i use react-native-firebase but it give gradle error to me. the error is :-
* What went wrong:
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.4,16.0.4]], but resolves to 16.0.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
>   The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.6,16.0.6]], but resolves to 16.0.4. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

I dont understand what i can do please Help me 
Thanks In Advance

Comment: See [expo push notification](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications) and follow given guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You must modify the file android> build> app> build.gradle and modify the following line

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
```

```js
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'  
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
  }
}
```